# which admin API can add the word lexicons at database level in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using MarkLogic version 8.

I am able to set all the other configurations of database using `Admin` API except `word lexicon`

Is there any way to add `word lexicon` using `admin` API.

I have to add `word lexicon` with `unicode codepoint` collation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're after the [database-add-word-lexicon()](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/admin:database-add-word-lexicon) method: http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/admin:database-add-word-lexicon

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $dbid := xdmp:database("Documents")
let $lexspec := admin:database-word-lexicon("http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint")
return admin:save-configuration(admin:database-add-word-lexicon($config, $dbid, $lexspec))
```

(Update the code according to your requirements)